# How to add AWS ELB access logs to logstash with S3 input?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-elb, logstash, elk

I'm using an ELK stack for server monitoring. My application's access logs which are from AWS ELB are stored in AWS S3. I am trying to add them to logstash with the following input:

```
input {
  s3 {
    access_key_id => "my_id"
    secret_access_key => "my_key"
    bucket => "my_bucket"
    region => "region"
    prefix => "AWSLogs/828557649675/elasticloadbalancing/eu-west-1/**/**/**/*.log"
    type => "elb"
  }
}
```

But nothing is added to logstash, what am I doing wrong? I there another way to add them to logstash?
The filter and output parts seems OK so I don't post them.

Note: I am using logstash 2.1 version

Comment: Does the IAM user you use have enough rights to get logs from S3?

Comment: Yes, the permissions are ok

Comment: @apanagiotou Did you manage to get this to work? Why are you using type => elb and not "string"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like the prefix should be, as the plugin does not support globs (*) :

```
 prefix => "AWSLogs/828557649675/elasticloadbalancing/eu-west-1/"
```

Full example:

```
input {
  s3 {
    access_key_id => "my_id"
    secret_access_key => "my_key"
    bucket => "my_bucket"
    region => "region"
    prefix => "AWSLogs/828557649675/elasticloadbalancing/eu-west-1/"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you add `sincedb_path => "/tmp/alb-sincedb"` and leave prefix like `prefix => "AWSLogs/"`?

Also it would be great if you install the latest version of input s3 gem. I believe I saw the changes there related to the iterating of objects inside of the bucket using the prefix by using V2 resources API. My current version is `logstash-input-s3-3.1.2.gem`.